# Livewire Simple Filter Issues

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using first time laravel livewire in my project. I am trying to create one simple filter option and this filter will trigger from a dropdown. My problem is when a dropdown value change its completely hide my component view.

I am not sure where i am making a mistake in this but i want to know the best way to resolve this.

my code is this Livewire component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Boat;

use App\Models\Product;
use Livewire\Component;

class Listing extends Component
{

    public $filter_option;
   // public $message;
    public $product;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->product = Product::where([
            'type_id' => 1,
            'status' => 1,
        ])->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

    }

    public function filter_speed()
    {
        $this->product = Product::where([
            'type_id' => 1,
            'status' => 1,
        ])->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
       

    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.frontend.boat.listing');

    }

  
}
```

My blade is

```
<select wire:model="filter_option" class="form-control" wire:change='filter'>
               <option value="#">Filter</option>
               <option value="speed">Speed</option>
             </select>

//or 
 <button wire:click='filter_speed'>Filter by speed</button> <!-- Simple button click -->
```

Comment: Are you sure you have your blade component content surrounded in one single <div>? And why do you have both wire:model and wire:change, this may be a conflict. You need just one action.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion in your case its not necessary to use Query on `mount()`.

But If in case of Filter u can use this method:

```
<?php
// Livewire 
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Frontend\Boat;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\View\Components\comment;
use Livewire\Component;

class Listing extends Component
{

    public $filter_option;
   // public $message;
    // public $product;
    public $orderBy = 'id';
    public $orderType = 'desc';

    public function filter_speed()
    {
        $this->orderBy = 'speed';
    //    $this->emit('filter_speed');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $product = Product::where([
            'type_id' => 1,
            'status' => 1,
        ])
          ->orderBy($this->orderBy, $this->orderType)
          ->get();
        return view('livewire.frontend.boat.listing', compact('product'));
    } 
}
```

```
 <button wire:click.prevent='filter_speed'>Filter by speed</button>
```

Instant of making many Query make one with custom variable